# Why does the restore purchase not work in local testing?

Tags: swiftui, in-app-subscription

During local testing in SwiftUI, when a purchase is made on the iPhone, clicking “Restore Purchases” on the computer or iPad does not trigger any response. However, if a purchase has already been made on the computer, clicking “Restore Purchases” will generate a restore record on the computer. It seems that each device is independent of the others, but the content across different devices has indeed been synced through iCloud. and it is unclear why this is happening.

I want to know why clicking “Restore Purchases” does not trigger any response.

Comment: Can you please show us some code? Learn more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example